# wrote a simple quiz code using two functions in python but a list is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

**Designed a simple trivia quiz using 2 functions, but I got an error,how can I fix this?:**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGJAT.png)
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File  line 31, in 
    run_quiz(Qlist)
NameError: name 'Qlist' is not defined**

Here is the code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKTiw.png)
***from random import shuffle
print('Welcome to the fun quiz!')

filename=input('Please enter the filename(quiz.txt)to get started:' )
with open(filename,'rb') as f:
lines=f.readlines()

numQ=int(input('How many questions would you like to answer (10-15)?'))

def questions(numQ):
'''This function shuffles the quiz bank and create a question list for the users to answer'''
shuffle(lines)
Qlist=lines[:numQ]
return Qlist 
questions(numQ)

def run_quiz(Qlist):
 '''Ask the user questions, determine whether the answer is correct, and count the correct answers.'''
right=0
for line in Qlist:

question, rightAnswer=line.strip().split('\t')

answer=input(question+' ')

if answer.lower()==rightAnswer:

print('Correct!')

right+=1

else:

print('Incorrect.The right answer is', rightAnswer)
return print('You got',right,'out of',numQ,'which is',right/numQ*100,'%.') run_quiz(Qlist)***

Comment: From what I see, you are calling run_quiz(Qlist) but you have not defined Qlist yet as it is only defined when you save the returned value from questions(numQ), and then pass that returned value into run_quiz()

Comment: how can i save the return value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return value like so. As Qlist is returned from questions, you call that function and pass it as a parameter to run_quiz

```
filename=input('Please enter the filename(quiz.txt)to get started:' )
with open(filename,'rb') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()

numQ=int(input('How many questions would you like to answer (10-15)?'))

def questions(numQ):
    shuffle(lines)
    Qlist=lines[:numQ]
    return Qlist

def run_quiz(Qlist):
    right=0
    for line in Qlist:
        question, rightAnswer=line.strip().split('\t')
        answer=input(question+' ')
        if answer.lower()==rightAnswer:
            print('Correct!')
            right+=1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.The right answer is', rightAnswer)
    return print('You got',right,'out of',numQ,'which is',right/numQ*100,'%.')

run_quiz(questions(numQ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! but another error occurred, could you take a look and help me with it? : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zikkki/Desktop/PSU/CS101/program implementation.py", line 30, in <module>
    run_quiz(questions(numQ))
  File "/Users/zikkki/Desktop/PSU/CS101/program implementation.py", line 22, in run_quiz
    question,rightAnswer=line.strip().split('\t')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: You are reading the file in binary mode. with open(filename, 'rb'). Just use 'r' instead of 'rb'